# Recommend Python GUI program/module/site

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x

I have been learning Python for a little while now, and I feel that I have picked up the basics. I want to begin making some projects in Python with a GUI, but I don't know where to start learning. Could anyone recommend to me a website teaching how to make GUIs, or a python module containing the necessary functions etc for making them, or even an third-party program/debian linux package (I have a raspberry Pi) for making python GUIs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, this kind of question does not fit the format of this site, see the [FAQ#dontask]. Questions like these tend to lead to vague answers that are also outdated very quickly. If we can help you with a specific problem, feel free to post another question though!

Comment: Try wxWidgets, PyQt4 and PyGTK and see which one you like best. I prefer [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro), but that's just my personal preference.

Comment: Sorry for posting a bad question, I will make sure to fully read the FAQ before answering anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming and http://wiki.python.org/moin/GUI%20Programming%20in%20Python. You have tagged your question als python-3.x, so you have to check yourself which of these frameworks is ready for Python 3.x. If Python 2.x is also an option, I would go for [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/). [Here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started) is the getting started page.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot, and thanks for such a prompt answer :)